# Reduction of order of a second order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let there be a second order linear homogeneous ordinary differential equation in its general form,
$y{''}+p(x)y{'}+q(x)y=0$ When the equation is of a particular form $F(x,y{'},y{''})=0$, I can easily employ change of variables with $y{'}=u$ and $y{''}=u{'}$ to reduce the differential equation to a first order one. What can be done to convert the equation into a first order in the case $y$ explicitly appears (when the form is $F(y,y{'},y{''})=0$) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a differential equation of the form:
$$F(y,y{'},y{''})=0$$
Substitute $p=y'$ and $y''=\dfrac {d p} {dx}=\dfrac {dp} {dy} \dfrac {dy}{dx}=p\dfrac {dp}{dy}$

But the general DE:
$$y{''}+p(x)y{'}+q(x)y=0$$
Can't be solved in most cases.